# How to find records modified since last retrieved

Tags: mysql, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have a table, which has a rather large number of records in it. This is key table, which needs to be loaded in our app for most activities. The records may also change sometimes throughout the day, and I would like to keep the users copy of the records up to date.

What I'm hoping I can do, is periodically query the database to find only the records that have been modified since last retrieved. That is, if there are 10,000 records in the table, and n records have been modified/inserted since the records were retrieved, I want to retrieve these n records from the server, to update the record set (in the applications memory).

Can you give me any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You need a modfication time column

Comment: Also look at `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` for a handy way to update immediately and avoid polling for changes.